# heroku twitter e_books: nothing added to commit but untracked files present

Tags: python, ruby, heroku, twitter

I'm pretty new to using ruby and python and github and all that stuff - the only programming I've ever done has been in a game engine. But I want to make a randomized twitter e_books using python-twitter, heroku_ebooks, and of course heroku. Everything was going according to plan until one of the last steps. I try to use the command `git commit -am "updated the local_settings.py"` but it just gives me a GIANT wall of red text (files I'm assuming from the looks of them) and says "nothing added to commit but untracked files present".

Trying to run `git push heroku master` results in it saying:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to "https://git.heroku.com/xanderbot.git"
```

Like I said I'm super new to coding like this so I really need to be told in layman's terms what to do, or just given a piece of code to slap on here so I can move on. Everything else was working perfectly until now and I've no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Is there a branch named `heroku` in the repository. If the answer is no then use: `git push -u origin master` or create a branch named `heroku`.

Comment: Not sure exactly where to check the repository but used 'git checkout -b heroku' to make a new branch and it looked like it worked, but when I tried to use 'git push -u origin master' it said the same thing as when I try to push heroku master. 'error: src refspec master does not match any.'

Comment: "it just gives me a GIANT wall of red text (files I'm assuming from the looks of them) and says 'nothing added to commit but untracked files present'." It would be helpful if you showed is part of the actual output, rather than a vague description. Also, what is the output of `git status`? It will tell you the names of any untracked files.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
git push heroku HEAD:master
```

Comment: Same thing as before. 

error: src refspec HEAD does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to "https://git.heroku.com/xanderbot.git"

Comment: Can you post the result of:
`git remote -v`

Comment: `git remote -v` 
`heroku https://git.heroku.com/xanderbot.git (fetch)`
`herokuu https://git.heroku.com/xanderbot.git (push)` 
`origin xanderbot (fetch)` 
`origin xanderbot (push)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem! For anyone with the same issue who finds this thread, I put the local file into the C:/ directory on my computer (don't know why it wasn't already there) and ran the following:

```
>cd C:/xanderbot
>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/xanderbot/.git/
>heroku git:remote -a xanderbot
set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/xanderbot.git
>git add .
>git commit -am "make it better"
>git push heroku master
>heroku run worker
```

and now the twitter bot is up and running! Thank you to everyone for your advice!